# Argmax of a trained supervised model!

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

**This question is mainly about how I can approach this problem. So if you know what extra assumptions I need to make to be able to address this question, please let me know**

Suppose you have some arguments $X_1,...X_N$ and a continuous value $Y$ associated with them.

You don't have any functional form for their association, but you have labeled data about $(x_1,...x_N,y)_i , 0 \le i \le M $; namely how they have been associated over $M$ instances of data.

You train a black-box regression model (DL, or an ensemble model) which maps each combination of these arguments (features here) to a predicted value. So at the end, you have a $\hat f(X_1,...,X_N)$ with a non-parametric $\hat f$!

Most packages in python implement it as

```
model.predict(x_1,...,x_N)
```

So you have a black-box model that gives you an output for any $(x_1,...,x_N)$.

What algorithm you can use to find the combination of values for these features that maximizes predicted value? Mainly, how can you approach this problem:

$argmax_{(X_1,...,X_N)} \hat f(X_1,...,X_N)$

follow-up: Is it possible to add a constraint to this problem; at least to have $X^*$ stay within training sample limits?

Comment: This question seems like “how do I optimize an arbitrary function with no assumptions about its functional form/smoothness/domain?”, unless I missed your point.

Comment: “Training sample limits” meaning what, exactly? You haven’t specified whether the domain is continuous, discrete, words, trees, etc.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy for domain, as I said in the follow-up, we may want to limit to the training sample limits, if it makes it easier.

For smoothness, is there any assumption under which we can address such question?

For functional form, you are right! We have a trained black-box model!

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy “Training sample limits” means our training $x_1, .. , x_N$ limits. So if we assume they are all continuous, we are able to define some convex hull for them.. the simplest could be $min(X_{in}) \le X_i \le max(x_{in})$ for $0 \le n \le M$ and $0 \le i \le N$